# Correct number of samples, based on new mean and variance

Tags: statistics, gaussian, mixture-model

I have a set of sample, sampled from a specific gaussian mixture. Then I update the mixture parameters (mean, variance, weights). Now, I want to correct (move) these samples by the new parameters. I don't want to randomly sample from the new mixture, just move the old samples to match the new parameters. How can I do that

Comment: You should ask this question on stats.stackexchange.com rather than here.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Expectation Maximization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm)

After updating mixture parameters (M-Step), you want to compute the expected membership values for every sample. An example can look like this

[image]

Where `A, B` are the mixture memberships (there can be more components, of course) and `Pa, Pb` are their relative frequencies with constraint `Pa + Pb = 1`. Those 2 steps can be repeated until the change of mixture converges to any small enough epsilon.